Bit bufferer doesn't behave as expected in C
I have to write individual Bits to a file (for huffman code). To do so I send bits to a function which buffers them until a byte is filled and then returns the byte. I can´t figure out why it doesn't work, the function outputs wrong bytes (but no errors).
Here is the bitsBuffer function:
// Buffers bits until one byte is filled, the returns it and return code turns positive
int bitsBuffer(char inByte, char nBits, char* outByte, char finish)
{
    int i;
    static short unsigned buffer = 0;
    static char unsigned offset = 0;

    // Very readable way to add nBits Bits to buffer
    buffer |= (inByte & ~(~0 << nBits)) << offset;
    offset += nBits;
    if (offset >= 8) {
        *outByte = (char)buffer;
        buffer >>= 8;
        offset -= 8;
        return 1;
    }
    if (finish) {
        buffer = 0;
        if (offset) {
            *outByte = (char)buffer;
            offset = 0;
            return 1;
        }
        offset = 0;
        return 0;
    }
    return 0;
}


I use this program to test the bitbuffer an then I pipe the output to xxd -b to view the bits:
#include "bitsHandler.h"
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    char a[] = { 0b0110, 0b1, 0b100010, 0b111, 0b100110, 0b0 };
    char b[] = { 4, 1, 6, 3, 6, 1 };
    char c[100];
    int counter = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
        if (bitsBuffer(a[i], b[i], &c[counter], 0)) {
            counter++;
        }
    }
    if (bitsBuffer(0, 0, &c[counter], 1)) {
        counter++;
    }
    fwrite(c, sizeof(char), counter, stdout);
}


I replicated the function on paper (went through every step by hand) and I can't find my mistake. Help is appreciated.
EDIT:
Expected output (piped through xxd, should be identical to a[] array):
00000000: 01101100 01011110 01100000                             V..

Actual output:
00000000: 01010110 10111100 00001001                             V..


Please [edit] and show expected vs actual output.

Probably fwrite(c, sizeof(char), counter, stdout); -> for (int i = 0; i < counter; i++) printf("%02x ", (unsigned char)c[i]);. Explain what you think fwrite does.

If there are already bits in the buffer, you add any new bits in front of them (<<offset) and then you always take 8 bits from the back. The resulting order of the bits is going to be weird. Like aAaa + bbB + cCcc -> cbbBaAaa cCc which is probably not what you had in mind. (correct ?)

~0 << nBits invokes undefined behavior. Change to 0u.

Can you be sure that you will not need to encode values that map to more than 8 bits?

@Gerhardh Yes, I try to implement the huffman code. That means I assign smaller sequences of bits to the bytes. (Theroetically I could use a codeword length bigger than one byte, but that is unnecessary in most cases)

This depends on the set of values you want to encode. For each value that maps to fewer bits, you get more values that need more bits to encode. If you want to encode 8bit integer values without any restriction, you will either use 8 bits for all of them or some will need more than 8 bits. (E.g. if you use 7 bits for one value, you get 2 values the need 9 bits) In that case, using a unsigned short may not be sufficient for your buffer.

// Very readable way to add nBits Bits to buffer?  Putting in that comment did NOT make the line after it "very readable" at all.  The fact that you felt you had to add that comment means the code ISN'T readable.

Apart from the fact that your bit order is gong to be a bit weird because you add new bits to the top of the buffer and take them off of the bottom, you have a bug in the finish path.
    if (finish) { 
        buffer = 0; // <<<==== This is a bug I think
        if (offset) {
            *outByte = (char)buffer;
            offset = 0;
            return 1;
        }
        offset = 0;
        return 0;
    }

When I dry run your test data, when your code hits the line marked "this is a bug I think" that zaps buffer there are still bits in it.Namely 0b01001 and offset is 5. Those last five bits are never getting written to the output.
As far as the bit order is concerned, I think it could be fixed by shifting buffer left by nBits, adding the new bits into the bottom and, if you have eight or more bits taking the top eight bits for your next output byte.
This is probably about right. It gives your expected output
int bitsBuffer2(char inByte, char nBits, char* outByte, char finish)
{
    int i;
    static short unsigned buffer = 0;
    static char unsigned totalBits = 0;

    // Note: nBits is assumed to b <= 8 !
    buffer <<= nBits; // Make space for the bits
    buffer |= inByte & ~(~0u << nBits); // Put the bits in the buffer
    totalBits += nBits;
    if (totalBits >= 8) {
        // Slice the top 8 bits off the buffer
        totalBits -= 8;
        *outByte = (char)(buffer >> totalBits); // Note: Shift before cast
        buffer &= ~(~0u << totalBits);
        return 1;
    }
    if (finish) {
        if (totalBits > 0) { // Test if anything is in the buffer
            // Pack the remaining bits at the top of the byte
            *outByte = (char)(buffer << (8 - totalBits));
            // Zap everything
            totalBits = 0;
            buffer = 0;
            return 1;
        }
        return 0;
    }
    return 0;
}

It might not be 100% correct if finish == 1 and a lot of bits in the buffer

First off, your bitsBuffer() interface (the return value is true if one byte is written to *outByte) is broken in that if you provide both non-zero nBits to send and you request finish true, then you may need to output two bytes, but the interface can only return one. You would have to require that if finish is true, then nBits has to be zero. Your current code will ignore the finish request if the nBits provided results in a byte being output. You would need to call again with another finish request.
Second, Huffman coding will easily produce codes longer than eight bits, even with a small amount of input. Your code should be able to handle longer codes. As it is, your interface can handle up to only eight-bit codes. As an example, ten different symbols with the frequencies 1, 1, 1, 3, 4, 7, 11, 18, 29, and 47, just 122 symbols total in the input, will result in two nine-bit codes. When you handle longer codes, your interface will also need to handle more than one byte produced.
Third, based on the desired bit ordering from your example, you are putting the bits in backwards. For your code, the second call will put those bits above the bits from the first call. So your example 0110 followed by 1 would put the second above the first, giving 10110. Whereas your desired output puts the first bits above the second, 01101.
Fourth, your finish is zeroing out buffer before sending the bits in buffer! You are erasing your information prematurely.
As an example, this will produce your desired output, will work with up to 57-bit codes, and handles flush properly:
#include <stdint.h>

// Write the low n bits of code, 0 <= n <= 57, to out[]. The bits above the low
// n in code must be zeros. If flush is true, then any remaining unwritten bits
// are put in the high bits of the last byte provided in out[], and the
// internal buffer is emptied. The return value is the number of bytes written
// to out[], in 0..8. stuff_bits() is not re-entrant.
int stuff_bits(char *out, uint64_t code, int n, int flush) {
    static uint64_t buf;
    static int bits = 0;
    buf = (buf << n) | code;
    bits += n;
    char *put = out;
    while (bits >= 8) {
        bits -= 8;
        *put++ = buf >> bits;
    }
    if (flush && bits) {
        *put++ = buf << (8 - bits);
        bits = 0;
    }
    return (int)(put - out);
}


Thank you, I decided to remove the finish (/flush) argument and flush whenever nBits (/n) is zero
